# Create constant in codemagic.yaml which is of type encrypted

Tags: yaml, codemagic

How would assign `FCI_KEYSTORE` below to a constant for reuse in my `codemagic.yaml` file?

```
:workflows
  integration-tests:
    name: Branches - main; Tests - UI; Release - None
    instance_type: linux
    max_build_duration: 120
    environment:
      vars:
        # Android
        FCI_KEYSTORE_PATH: /tmp/keystore.keystore
        FCI_KEYSTORE: Encrypted(Z0FBQUFBQmdfY05ObmQxSVdVZVJKdWJRVXJQOTd4VFNSdmtwalJlZHhUX095eVZURW40VXNNWXVRdEdUYlJZaGl1WjFNazlTSmZIeG0xZS1za0hwSkNnN0FMejJqcDFlWkRIaE1qMHJVRlJPLXB1Q1lQUERXQlh5a0Nrb3NSQ2lMTmk3dEpVd1IxX3BreEl4N2Q5TUxURXN4Q2N3N1BZeVYwdWdfN1l5UlczN09RVG5HYmxOQ3lBZXJEMGM4Y1VMLVFKYlB4eXV2ZXdaN2Y1ZEJ2UUVhcVdFLUNSY3ltRGlza205SVFqN3B4ZWwwUU9YRFgyVlZtZ2FReXVNSWR4VVlMNk9qd3JTbnZRLVV0V013M0ZXWkRGSEpoc0JkQ0xaZ21ERVVaaFNFU0o2eDRvREhuLV8xT0pTSFlfUGlfalJNNWQ2NFVyU0lnSlQ0YWlYRUlNclVTTXp6NndFOXVmajlwbTZmcUJxaG4tb2s1VHhESy05ZE1ibkIwS3pvUHUtTGdlSXFCU2lnOTdrQzlXMVRwaFhNazFUOXg0Vl9kQy1aVXpkTFVaRkN2Ujl4NUpmajBXUVNCQnRtbXlmT2RydEwtUS1RRmtGWWI4c0htT3RUOGI3MHBsa19xekNHR21SclJ3U2lPQXJydFpBZGR6UUlkWkNjUE9yS2loUHNSQURDZDFfaHl5VHVYYk1UcjBOd082X1lxNnBqUUZ0aHBvaGJzcEU5VmZuZUFLLWlycDZVYXYyYm9IY1ZxZ2l1dk1QeVlkeGF1YlBaRTBuZTdiMXhoUUthdnpPcDA0UEluc1UxSDBwRU5YdTdvckkwS2JRcm9WX05fT1Q4V3I2UTZxQjFqcGljNFpxd2IzejhydXQ4YmlxYzhjb0Q0aGhxWlNNckxTZHpWaXJRS08tcF83U19Ycmo1TUVPLUhVRlBrUXJJeGVRb2J6ZnRjeHpqeEFLSzFoNWMwMmZrUjN1eFljNGpzOUhfQWlCYU5iT2syYmhJTmpLWkR3YW83ZTFreWZkZ3FtZkttTjNqajR6YTJPeW1mY3lYLTFoMTF5QUU0UTRYa2VYOVhQWWZWU0pDRWljX0MxQnBMTkdwdkxfNnRyR3d1ZzViYU5sV2IxZC04S3ZZV2lwdWoyOUY5MnY5T2l1R1ltNkhrTlRIUnNqVEltSE1jbUJPamt3NldzZ2Z4VVZBNFVkZHIxdFZCTEh0eUFVd3g4bnowZFIwOVI2OG5WN1ZBZUhuQTE3Wkdkel9aejlrVW1oUXhOUVM1eDZHYk0xcGlCXzdvYTNPNHZRc3J5dFNEUXc2ODZ1VWJCd0ZwVGoyY3lBSmV4d3Nkb2Z5Y1c5bHM3UnAxMlNCTFhSZ0pNQWFrTGNlclZFNGtUcktXMnk5bnVYaExXT2VCT1R5MkNXRi1FRTZoYW1KZUI1UnNlaGVzandEOWxYcFFZem9FQXpQSXo1Q21PcHhENTJ1RzBORlFlbFBEYkJwUWtnVWo0ZjEyZk9sUHJaMWw0T0lndWVZSUxKaWNLWFlwalJGUmJXbnI5MGpyYlJZcGFEY3V5c2RUR1g2TExlRFc3MEpJdUdtMmkzQWRuVk84akUyb2RKRHZuckx1YnRiQUVocDBqSmo5R1pYNENKaWJlcHVkeWVicGdJZWxXNUtURVA1c0ZkQW1EMllpdWxCSFNnU1RGMi0wQkswY0F3bENobEt3bEluanQ2bGJVWk9UOHJQMV9sSTRqZmtncl9Fd2dkNlgtWUZjNm5WTk1hbDdRRTZ1Y01jLXh0c2dJYVBscU5mZHVVVFFmaldJaU5QSllDRUN3Y3NoOTFHcERFdkhSVWFVam54S19aTkpPaElRcjRuVlBMdGR6VEJkd3I3MENZWl8ya21lMFNBMXRzNDRGcDZtUnJzOGVMNExtRF81UEprcXVaTklBWXl4UHEyZG8xQlZSTDBTZUNBZThCNlBUQUhMV0kxRWtMOFhzVFdFa0hGZGdRTkJHRXF4RmdvM0RvQ1VlTHNqTjN3V3BvM3hQSWd0Zm1wSGtWcUFUeVNmTEs2cWZiTkI0M3cwd2NWVTFWVTBDMTBXaTZiczJjMEhNR1V1cU5VeHFJRWNudWFyMHJPNUVyMkt6RDVKVWJXOXpydm96MVJfY3FsWmlFMHU0SFJfUE5ERmJBS21WT3V5cVBUcDNsS0RqT3VjOVhJdzRjZGoyZ3ZHNU9GZUlPcDJHbFdpWFRXYVNidWZlUGw2R21wNzV5LUttU2JfS0NacWZsSGl1WHljVnoxZzdQLWpta0xsa2tQRHV5cXlLZXhreWxjMzNmeEJJdDE3TW9PUmo1VUl2b1JlSWMzRGRtc3dQMk9sRXZTUlNIVWtUSFQxS2hmMk5jbEtZNUgteG9vaUdvbVlOSEJIc21zcjI4UnBkWEhRaDZVY19hZHA5LTFXVExyTGZ2VGFJY0ZKTE0xR3FxMXBQWmVVWkVPZzZCUUhOclE2OTFxby12blpjelhwR0RYVkZQTUhIY283MFh4UGh6NXFaSVA4OU5ha3BlMHU1ZUIwSjJ3bDY2S2J0VkhHblhtajRiazd6U09fbDhnUlY4Z3pSajRoQ240ZnpjaEpUSm9pTkcycjVCa1hzNjVXdUpZQy1OeUZRaXd2Vm1GSjlHUEZhY29WcURIWGtIdUFMeERldURId1VzVlZYS0k4bHo2RUZCUEZoYlpmenJSTExNNDNMRTg2MzVLUTF5ZlRkYU54ZEdtMmhwcVphQVo5c0Q5emdmYlg2SVVoMVdqR09kX1BjZFFRZ2pJWFVlTlZTUWRwRnJxNGszSzg4VUowTGV5NV9VcW1HT0JicjJHYk81Y1dfUlk4YjJrVDExZG1ZWHZaWXZoU1k5b08yY0V1aGRDVXNmOEVDalpjVHFORlJ4WmZLUkJDNzFpQk1RYUdiak53SUUxb2tYQXhDU3EtYV9lSDlEYklmS3hnTmRDZUtkdlMyTjNrMjROcFFtVnRBdHhfTlJZal9NTFJsWG9HWTU2bnBhOTlKY1J2MEdWZm9NS1RXeTNoRzh4LU5Jb3otT0FEV1ltT0o0QlItNFZZYi03RkdpU1NWeFd2Uk9MVnUwTWN4VVpja2MwdVlObEdsbFc0am5OXzhNcExQcndMblh1WnUyNFpNQTNkQ1ZudEkzc2laYXdGelByT2lEQmJBTWRsTnhBTEI1b0V6TmFZcmtvVzFvU19WeWtSOTZkdUZFUjU1T3BoM1FxZlBQcGJwWHNfYzNOM0hkLXVUTWRCeTBPUDFlMHpWd3BxSUs5NnBIdGhycUQ4QWh1d3prTXhkYTVydzVGM19nS1RtcWNUVzRleXlxSm1meXROSUN5VUxPOExLYTJHWlJrcnZqMllmbFk3THpxRlZVeUgwTWh3OUEwTnZnU0NzejAtRzl0VTlYYVcyMmxLcm96eTRiWXlERUd3aVRCX0FEMXMtRHFVRDY5US1wbmYxa0R3a2loaG5sblNWd0p5d3Y0UTE4N0Q2NTJSdkhUTFF6di05NzRIbzBIRTFEX204ckxzME55aEhmc19Vd1JXQlNXNFpsSnF0aWxYOWRsZkYtNC1DdWxkLWZyQVFOR0h5VFNMWTNuRk1CUnpEczlNWXQ3cnNUOHhyRzBMNGVhcUM3UGFXeXl3QTVpNDJDWFRuRjVCM2p5TEduWldySTFtM2FmVGxXQ0MwelFoVGI2a21PU1BWUE1VWWY3YTBoQ1VUcV9Vbk8tWENzQVdZU013VEswRzhDUjBsc1FfamJqZWItNmVGR1N0Umc3UUhRLVNBNjRjZmw4Sm9NZGl0OUlOWjZmRVlxckxvNzVVaUJmbzJYLWJTQzB3b2hRcktiMTRCLUhRZExlci1yUjI5R0xLbU1BNmlhMXIwZi1hTUNKelZNWVFiOXBCY3FIYW5DcWthU2Vwdk9YTTBVdGRrLUZvWDRqYmdQbW1zZ3RnRk9oT2JmajBNNzNhWHdTaWg4VFR3T1ptelBGY3c1NGJOSVE1STdNcm10cDB5Uk43TTNJb1pGRjI3RzM1NUNSWHRYb2lmTVFqN010UnA1ODNreF9UWk5QMVpVSk5rVl9IcVFGZUNXY0RTUXVicDZFV3FCUFBjTFQtaUZNMks0TGdzTlBuaXFveEpJREFoR1JabVBZcWFjbFB0T1ZMR2txRVhaSTlIaEJTZHl3TFQtUS1uUUpPUDUwX2twTjlVOE9UWV9PRmdQOG1KWkN3OTh3Tzk1Z3R1c2pVVW1qT1Y1UGhiNkZnbF9jTlpaMVRlTS1udkw1R1lBTGY4ekE4UHEtRHk2M0U3WWkwU1FVYTVGSU1pdktwZjBHZkNvbDFORm5keHNqTFB3LXR2OGhkVWxuZ2M3QUwxczREd3VfYXY4ZXJzcG81OUxqSC1fRmFjQkFyMlc3bEVLMC11RUVsZENhZnZvZUtPMkk3ZkdSd25Xa3N1NC01bU9GenpmeTJVd0JVdFdIdzM5cXVBakJXNF95WmhOSnVtdllwaUNYN2dfcEYweVVJcG42enVUQ1pGNUV1eGE2cTRwOXZWQTdOMzhZekxmcXZjQTNJN3RGOGhUUU1oWV82YVBYYU5nVnhnMG5yUUFvdDl6NnRRNDFLYkphSERmeHdJU3gzR2hSYjBISFBKOTBJTEZIeU45ODNJQW56OVljVDVyTEtNV2hUR3ZaX1ZJT2NHN3piRjFZRnJneVVHOUtCSl9wVU9pY1Mtb0VvLUhrRWlPQkowaTJXdWNJN0lPVGY0NXhueTlWNGdrR0lFT3Q0dFRNMXRMdDJPYXhSMHBUODUwLVRYRUJMNGt2LXZQTGw1VDZ1aVd0SVRPLU9FVjZ3UW5fRGVqODNqVlp1UFNodTRlNmxMUGU3eFpRM1hqYmx5NFJnQWNoWWpsTjVPb1pOV1lKdFBzd2h2OTd6dWpsYmhhNmtzQjVocFA1SDQ2ZndQczRIRFczbnVMSmYyeGZkUHNIWGNIVnd0aFhnY1lGUGxTY1FtTk9LU0t0WnNQXzRCVDJ0aHZMT295MUp2OWhHU1Z0dHFsRjV4ZmR2MUZMV3NmMjR0M3hYNi10a0ltVG5RRGpoZm5Ec0xYbVpaRUpwQXYwMXV6Sm8xeGtoVWxsOWVMUG1vb3JBTW5GQWdJSF9WMDhJOVZkY0FJN2J3bVB4djdaNk5wRU9Fd3d5NTRuVjlkM25Tb2t0MDV3NVBCdlV4cjJtWERKcDVKdWpsZ0pXTTloeTVXYWxtSjg0ajVveTRyUy1MN1dBdlVQbFBRcGE0WW5UanZNQkR3M1BoSVpWSEdfQlotWUs2VzVZelNya2s4WUZkWTNKaC0xWXpENERKQkFUbkFaQlR5U3RiNkRGZ0s0eVB3RmhwU2tXVTNKRzhyS2VrV0tPRHR2Mm5ibUo3eFc4anUzSlNoM1QtSlhWcE1qMTUzS1VtYksyQW9jWHZleXNiYXQyN1JGUDlZaVR0c2lwNEtESEtxNEQtYms1ZVZ3WGFNNnRSNUk3VEktYjVsbWlJMFpDN2ZTQ19SNy10ZkJpRXN1QXFHenNMN0ozYm9wTDR6cllNTS1mVDlUcmQ2Y2VfcmdhaFBkOHNfbWxVM2pBU2lJeDJPOXJvMC00MjYzNGFXYkU5SWNTbTc3aFdJeVJWUlZLTWVhaUpyMG9KVTlNNFVHVmtvc1hXbDRscURDempPZ2UtZjVFRVVyVDZDNklaUHhTSksxYXAwY1B1RVNwY2dJb0MxTG96TFlOWnB3cTlVcm1nenc4MzYtZTl3VkdPUVptTFNfUjF3SXNOcXZxQTByajAxVDJhTmhCTGEwU2trLTdQUFh4YktHbGNOWXhnbUJXNEVUczFIb2V3X093SEJudlJ1UWc1Qkh4a0RObzJGeExJOTg5dnlsUWdab09fa2dGM2g2R0RvcVMtSE9RNFB6WVM1bmpYUDBqYnNpRTN6MWljQzA4TzRLdG1SYW1EWi02aUJ6RF9BN1RvOEZ3YmMzbWNBUzdrb2dOS1dFOFhVcGpkbjVyODlDMVdSRkM3M19mRnA5RTRxc1hwOTQ2U0tmVnZNeVhRNmpxWHAyMVljZWw1TkVYeU5IVFA3T3cxaG1FWHhXa1BSc3VQaU9hWDVnUUZpd2V4TUlUdEhfNjZNTWxIY19RVmZrWVRYT2tVd2dsTmd5eFFnczBvRC1QMHhtNEt4bS1TSUc0TklFbnZJU2lwUFJPOHFGTV9fZU1KSVRwcC16Z01JZi11OWxXQVNDRVFIODBwT2haeVVYTXhQNlEyUXFUNUZvQU1ERkR3bElUWmowZWZuUDlpTC02YjJCdldTQ0pfVGdZLWZuckpSdU00cUJzcW9xcFJyc0lqdHFqX1hnVzdJUFJ2cjFnSTZtNklNVzVJbjRzaDFwdm9mb3VkNndNSlZlWjNqR2JoV3UyT09RQk54RmYwTjY1c3Z2ci1oMUZOeGNjNUpfT1g5RnlsR2VQS25OZjNXQWZOVVZaazdwSHVLUHJ2bDMyVml2TnFneGZneUVuOGxxUEF0U0tUMTFjTlc2UGVqSVpBbWYwdHVxMGdNOUpEb3RVX2RadVIyTzlCR3VMeENSd2U1b2N5X3V0Um5McS1SMThlSWFSX181OWhBU2M3cnZ6eTJWTlJoNjdzb1hVckx1SEIydDNWY2ZpcDdHbF9Lc0tUVDhyUVBwOGZpM3dmMlFyZW1KTVVsWlVDOHlsMnJrZFZXTEhNNmpDeUNkZ08zdGdyRllvRW9sOWJxTlNQTzZ1VVRCRVBHLUR4eUNpUHhrSmEtTlVQcEp0ME9rQmViQ09yNkxlcXQ5dFdXanVYNUhEcWVkekNNRjFTUHFEOUx6WXVwOXFYcWxLSFI5QUJBdlJmQ2pabDVWd2cwMTNRYi1heHhRY05jUlRSYmVPREhCMGF6WUhnTEdDNTU4RXlTV0lrNWxQeGVMT0Q2VGl2ZVg3S1c0WTcxN3VITkg4QVdrVlp5Nnpmd1Fla1A3SWJVS3ZMZGtaTUZRRUc0aDZWbW0zd0NWaGZaNWtYNU5LQlk0cXJ5VHZEbU5SLWtWRWRKZkdnZXEtSnhWWTdWNW4wUlNDeEFuNVZiMVVEZFppV2x5OXVFSnd6NktNTkQ1ZEF3RkhWa1gyNVRNWmZxOFhIRkhfQVhNRUYwMkpMbW1MMVdoRkMxSXVaVVZMTjQ1M0pZbTFtblZScnVQTEhUMkRtd1NPdmpPS251emJwVWZOamUwLVRIYjBXZmY1ZUJsanlsX2RvdE5tOWhYUzd4ay10V0RfS2NRY01KV28wNmgtZ1huWmljU3dWemZXZXpDLXNLYS1xNWZmR2U3REJITlVsNVRmVmFOeFo5bkI4RXdsS0dxdldTczRhd0NiSmFEWFI1d3Mtank2NVl6YjNZLTUtYmdnZHZUUzAyemxJY3FlWldteHZmN0FQQ1dBQVRoZ0xjbWdOQWVHQy1PTnQwcHdUNXl1cUZlWGdBOXY5aEh3U3FqU1JobE9OT3FDQXpzZlRGSTBhVjZXOVo2VDBnZ192X0FSS2JQZnJWU3NjLThsbElEVFB0WEU1NFpLSEwzV1pLTzlkek1QUEREcTdiai1sU00tZUpmVm9Zcm5tbUdvdGh6dXpJRzdrdFRnTDFidVl6bW0wSk1sQUpYSklCdHVSXzFPRG5fNGFCM1NBbVlPcHN5WHNLS2RMZ3VLYWN2OUlhTFctcUNsOEdqbU4zUC1jaXR1UnNyRjh3NEg0TWhMMDJVUEFhaHlKeW1pSnFaT1lrVU5NMUY2WnB3bDAtVlNyRlZaWlFXbV9tTkhabVpjbnJ2Z3R3TVoxZ1ZSNHg1bUNJVXBGeWwxU0s0d3dLZjc4Tm1jR21IMDFSUEtCLU96MDN0c2J6Q3dVUlVpN1RTa3llckdjcS12ektDcWN1dXQ1MGxqdG1GSVlSUFJ5MzBNRlVZX1MwY3BMbkFaTHNkb2ZmaVdiTzRzRW14b2FseVBpeXFCNkw0bkdjbWJ5cHhabEZYTlpuOFRhSVV6ZkNQVFJWTUE4Nmt1MEdMNG5PaHVhNmpvTXYwa3lXdjRTUDk3RnY5aHBOS2Vjb3JieWxwX3ptTTJGZlVKNkJoMllGdE5iOExBaDNaNFY0VHktYk9zMXp1X0FvU1VzdUdPUm8yZWFVWEtCQ1RKcG5hSldnSzFrSFpBRlhGdlpwRkR5N1gxcGwtbUFtRVI4dGxxN2Izb0ttenY1bTJGOEZuM2hkcDRYd2xCSE11dHBuS0JVNHgyMmdKWG13MTRWZnpxUVpLNTl4RXFaRW1jLWZUNU5XVm94UFpVWTJOV3FKa1BIZ0R3eXpSNnpJM1ZDV0ZkS1RGbFFmLUxNTnhHSzlRWks3RnZxZl9RT2hIRDlxUlhMN2VUa2FXaElScC1hMmhCQ2hRS09nTWt2aFR2YzlNc2hBT2lORjlyQVVNbC1YUG9fMnoxQjZQcGs1TTJuVjVBbnBMOGxQVW5ZSDVGVWVUUnh2VWlCOUxyUE9WdjA5Q0IzTHBvSGk2Q25wN3FCUnY1YWZFdXBwZDVhTHpfUnNaelR3ZlhJS0VhT0FwX1RFUnkwYWJ3UklrZW52OTZscUdBcy1ERTVOQWRSRmJ3aHNDZmlNRkJCd3dhdnN2SHc1cFRFeEhRNGFRVThfRnRfLWhHMm0td0VfX2ZzMFoyVzdsTEhGRndQVTN1dnQ3ZnFaOUNBX1d6UWVWX2VtQXB5MkZDYWhUUUEtQVNxUzNmWlc1V09QbmRLR3NoeEZLREYzZTJkRi1jclRack1pdkNpQjZ0RE03R01MRHgzLTBzX0VpX0RmV244RlRyeWpvc0pTd0dkVmtVMEduejlZX3p5N2tGTDNOZzVfYTdkS2hIZjU0X2pPZ0c3bXJzbUxlY1l4QUQ4UHhHdG5JQWNacnctM0JiQjE1VHZjNUdjNXZseTBnZmVVVG9JRmc0bjI0Y2xCNVNOTTlkM2xkV0hHb01BcnljUWZRMk0zVGhDUklMT3RfYzRrQnQxSzBHSjJHM0lTRHllc0hrajM3MzN4cGZERlZmU2FWTEI3MDVrSl85bDdybVVPeHNmNUVEVWl3TVd6TkJBOU1OdzVIREJlWEl0LXZ4RDBYU0h6LTU1ZDltWmUzZzZROWZZSVM4ZHAwak80TXRLWm9NSWFEcWx3Y09hOU42M3RrUktzTzVfZlFWQUtZUEVRaWg1R1JlY3ZvekVvWTgxZTFYbEZjcUlxdEJVdXp4VE1zT255RURHSjBnbC1rR0FtRnZLLW1GUDhBandjblhvVGJ3dU5lNi1MVHV1WlNCUWp0ZDZubXV3dGFwdlJaUnRPUnc0Ujh1cjdhQnNSYTJ4a19sTmRJNDVuM2JzTzlaTVZCM21tTEZLN1FDWk94c1h5bXk1cU1OWjZBbDZVUGdUN3RJV0l4RHJiUS1vRGw0YW9QdmpBYTBqOTc2VXA4OU1zLS1xU1JDQ2RmVGoxcVJzekpIVXhlYkNLUFZ2RTdISWdGS1NSLW40cm4wMVg2a3hZS3ZsR2pBWHNFaVpYQVlHd3k2eWNwX0lTaFotU2VpVFpRZU5WbnRUc1VSZUNnQmU4aWMtODBqelo3Y3E1dXpmOEJrbVg0UlY0Z1J2RjBmRTFYbzUtYzNqVE83LXY5bjJpNDB2UzFYcnZ2S04wTURFMWNlLU50S080SWJaOUx1MmxSaEZBZjR4WDV2TzZtMWNkQWw1Umw0MExacHE1SGZtVkZETTFBc2Fyb01ydU9kZDVwUUhUNTNRS1BzOERHMG82R3lhNldoSEZCdlFLX1pTRXJ0cDh2MHBwRzFEQ3JURlNuRWhYZU1BTFRKUzNOZnBtelZDUXg3cHVCSU9zQXlvTzlrLXdSSHJDQktFdUUxVWVha3E5VTVBODJJa085b0YyQTNTYjlZZVVnMG1VM0xhb0NxdTJiSzZUZlctSVgtUmxkczdXX2s4OXV5T1h0UF9QXzJMakRQWkdHTUJZM05IVllVbVlNd1lDNGp4RDI0VVNGT0ppRjlVdWNKZ1o0NjNYRGVlQ2dZRV94LW5tdXRVVmdqOHBVSy1ncWh0VWhEQTIxOWFyQ0I2QzRMV0xEbUhSQlZUcjFSQVRRMGtqd1licHdMb3BOeXYzQ09nZmtwb3AxMENvMnZ4MHN5OFl0dXpHb09UWlNQaDA1eWhhR1lFUnlhakJtM2oxSEJvVDRmbTJQazVZdGRaV2owX3lXaVFWajFscTAtWWxEUGpEU08zU21SZW8wOUs2aHJjR2plSTdHeTB2UXppMHpDUXVqbWJNSW5XamYtWllHQjRUZE92SWtodGtzS1hVcjNkM1F3cWNfSVlZNmozcWZ0eDFBOWt6R0MtU2FBLVR4NWR6dnhHVnI3cnB2bjhpVk13SDhQa2k1S2xjeGxMMVlyaVU1ZEpNSGExbXV3ZjVzQjZqLVpHc29CdmEyUmk0dERUUGU2SHRqZmFuME1keE5aUEE5QzRjeWxJZkZiRGFNYktPSnI3bzRNRDY4bktDZmtPUjFuSC1QV182MnZmaElyejZXOF9PMDR0X29XV2U5dkp2NFMweHY2OW5QcFpPRGh0Q1JDQUZnTXJDOERELUp5MENpZXNTSkdsTG02QT0=)
```

I'm trying:

```
definitions:
  environment:
    vars:
      - &package_name
        PACKAGE_NAME: "com.some_company.some_app"
      - &fci_keystore
        FCI_KEYSTORE: Encrypted(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)
```

But getting:

> Incorrect type. Expected "string | integer | number |
> boolean".yaml-schema: Environment variables

Answer (score 1):

this yaml code doesn't show any syntax errors for me

```yaml
definitions:
  environment:
    vars:
      - &package_name
        PACKAGE_NAME: "com.some_company.some_app"
      - &fci_keystore
        FCI_KEYSTORE: Encrypted(...)

workflows:
  integration-tests:
    name: Branches - main; Tests - UI; Release - None
    environment:
      vars:
        <<: *package_name
        <<: *fci_keystore
```

Also you can create alias for group of variables (note there is no `-` when you define variables)

```
definitions:
  environment:
    vars: &android_vars
      PACKAGE_NAME: "com.some_company.some_app"
      FCI_KEYSTORE: Encrypted(...)

workflows:
  integration-tests:
    name: Branches - main; Tests - UI; Release - None
    environment:
      vars: 
        <<: *android_vars
```

You can validate codemagic.yaml syntax in Visual Studio Code or go to codemagic.io > your App Settings > `codemagic.yaml` tab